# Customizing Amazon SNS email notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

We are developing Custom Commenting System in which email notifications will be sent to all the subscribers to the post just like "Disqus". We found AWS provides Simple Notification System(SNS) which does a fairly good job of sending mass email notifications and manages subscribers and topics, but I did not found any article on which the format of email notifications can be changed as all the emails have Amazon Branding.

Is it possible to send through Amazon SNS?

1. Custom Email without Amazon Branding?
2. Custom Subscription Link?
3. Custom Un-subscribe link?
4. Custom From Email Address?
5. Attaching Companies logo in the email.

Thus removing Custom Amazon SNS branding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe any customization is possible. For custom e-mails you should use Amazon SES instead. You would however need to manage unsubscribes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are already using Amazon SES for Change Password related emails, but it  also means we have to create the infrastructure to publish the topic, send emails to all subscribers, may be using Amazon Sqs and Amazon Ses.

Comment: what about now in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use custom message. You will have to do it in lambda. Just extract the contents and use the sns publish api.

See this link for a sample. Just put s3 event on lambda, then in lambda run the sns publish

https://mattgadient.com/2016/06/14/creating-custom-notification-text-with-amazon-s3-and-sns-via-lambda/

Comment: I can't see any custom message for the successful confirmation on the [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html), I think you could change the initial email but the, confirmation after that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the sender (**AWS Notifications**), but you can change the body with Lambda or custom code running on your EC2 or on-premise instances. Here's Python code for sending a custom SNS message:

```py
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = "My Custom Message"
    client = boto3.client('sns')
    response = client.publish(
        TargetArn="YOUR_ARN",
        Message=message,
        MessageStructure='text',
        Subject='My Subject',
    )
```