# Changing email body , header AWS SNS notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

[StackOverFlow Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591082/customizing-amazon-sns-email-notifications)

i have been searching around and what i got on SOF is this question which is very old. Now question is any changes have been made by AWS for this? 
I am getting sns notifications but email is quite complicated and Header is too long. 
is there any way to customized these things?

Comment: What do you mean, *"header is too long"*... ?

Comment: i mean this "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Notification - New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances" this is email header.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in solution within AWS SNS service to modify the notification, however as an alternative you can consider the workaround of using :

```
 SNS → Lambda → SES
```

Configure a Lambda function to be triggered by your SNS topic. The function retrieves the SNS notification and within it modify the content as desired and then send an email via SES.

***Kindly keep in mind that there will be additional costs (Lambda & SES charges) introduced due to this workaround.***